# Regular expression for two underscores

Tags: sql, regex

What would be the regular expression to match a string with two underscores breaking up a 3 series of characters. This can also be a SQL 'like' statement if that is possible.

Match:

```
b_06/18/2012_06:02:34 PM 
y1289423_06/14/2011_03:06:35 AM 
23479693_11/01/2011_06:12:55 PM
```

Not Match:

```
CCC Valuation_b_06/28/2012_05:57:20 PM 
CCC Valuation_CCC Valuation_b_06/28/2012_05:57:20 PM 
doc1_2.pdf 
testdoc.txt
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? This seems like a pretty straightforward regex. If you don't know anything about regexes, you should find a tutorial first, then come back and ask a real question.

Comment: I have tried different regular expressions already but I am not sure how to have it catch only the two underscore strings and not the three.

Comment: Can you post those regular expressions so we can see what you have? You might not be far off. We're not going to just give you the answer, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all of the data is consistent with your examples, then this should work:

**EDIT**:  Updated to match the whole line.  This will preclude any substring matches in the invalid list.  However, it assumes that OP does not want to match any substrings.

```
^[a-z0-9]+_[0-9\/]+_[A-Z0-9:\s]+$
```

For example, in python:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'b_06/18/2012_06:02:34 PM'
>>> pattern = '^[a-z0-9]+_[0-9\/]+_[A-Z0-9:\s]+$'
>>> m = re.match(pattern, s)
>>> m.group(0)
'b_06/18/2012_06:02:34 PM'            # <======== matches from valid list

>>> s = 'CCC Valuation_CCC Valuation_b_06/28/2012_05:57:20 PM'
>>> m = re.match(pattern, s)
>>> m.group(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):    # <======= does NOT match from invalid list
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: This is close, but it actually matches this case when it shouldn't:

CCC Valuation_CCC Valuation_b_06/28/2012_05:57:20 PM

Comment: @anton2g I corrected my solution.  The assumption is that you're not interested in matching substrings, since this will match the whole line.  If that's not correct, let me know.

Comment: This for whatever reason did not match any of the strings that should have matched.

Comment: @anton2g not sure what to tell you.  I updated my solution with a demonstration of the regex in Python.  As you can see, it matches one example from your valid list and does NOT match an example from your invalid list.  The only thing I can think of is that there is something unique about the language you're using, or a problem with your implementation, or maybe I'm not understanding the data you're trying to match.  Based on the examples you supplied, the regex seems to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
^[^_]+_[0-9\/]+_[0-9:]+\s[AM|PM]
```

Comment: Remember to indent four spaces for code (or surround the code with backticks `). Otherwise, Markdown will eat your lunch in all sorts of unwanted ways.

Comment: @Telemachus Thank you for the tip. I never knew that before.